# Bad request in MEAN stack app trying to append to an array in a schema

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am trying to pass an array of interest rates to a mongoose schema consisting of accounts.
I want to store interest rates that change at certain dates.

However, when I trigger the create function my dev tools tell me I have done something bad:

```
**400 Bad Request**
```

I have been using [this](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/511) as a template.

The view: has been disconnected so that I only pass:

```
var interest = {
    rate: 1,
    date: Date.now()
};
```

The controller that does the updating:

```
// Create new Account
$scope.create = function() {

    // Create new Account object
    var account = new Accounts ({
        name: this.name,
        desc: this.desc,
        interests: []
    });
    // PROBLEMATIC PART
    // Store interest:
    var interest = {
        rate: 1,
        date: Date.now()
    };
    account.interests.push(interest);
    // PROBLEMATIC PART END 

    // Redirect after save
    account.$save(function(response) {
        $location.path('accounts/' + response._id);

        // Clear form fields
        $scope.name = '';
    }, function(errorResponse) {
        $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
    });
};
```

The mongoose schema:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


/**
 *
 * Interest Rate Schema
 */
var InterestRate = new Schema({
  rate:{
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
    trim: true
  },
  date:{
  type   : Date,
  default: '',
  required: 'When is the interest to be updated',
  trim: true
  }

});

/**
 * Account Schema
 */
var AccountSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Account name',
        trim: true
    },
    desc:{
      type: String,
      default: '',
      trim: true
    },
    interests:
        [{ type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'InterestRate' }],
    amount:{
      type: Number,
      default:0,
      trim: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});

mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);
```

Comment: seem to be missing `mongoose.model('InterestRate ', InterestRateSchema );`

Comment: Adding that line after the InterestSchema and adding "Schema" to the name of the InterestSchema did not help. Instead I just rewrote the line containing: [{ type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'InterestRate' }] to handle an inline map of rates and date: [{rate: Number, date: Date}]

Answer (score 0):

you can try by leaving the interest rate as a frond end structure and not define it in the model, then in the account schema set interests as type of [] and just push the objects

```
var AccountSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Please fill Account name',
    trim: true
},
desc:{
  type: String,
  default: '',
  trim: true
},
interests:
    type:[],
    default:[]
},
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}
```

});

just like this